# CoffeeScript - Manually declare variable

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, scope, coffeescript

**Question: Is it possible to manually declare a variable in CoffeeScript**

I'm currently starting with unittesting for CoffeeScript, while going through a tutorial I came to a point where I had to use the `before()` and `after()` functions. While you can declare the variable in JavaScript where it has to be, you can't do this in CoffeeScript afaik.
One (but not best practice) solution would be to add them to the window object ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743007/can-i-add-attributes-to-window-object-in-javascript)). The code I'm working with is from http://sinonjs.org/.

This is the code I'm testing with:

```
describe 'Fake server', ->
  before(() -> server = sinon.fakeServer.create())
  after(() -> server.restore())

  it "calls callback with deserialized data", () ->
    callback = sinon.spy()
    getTodos(42, callback)

  # This is part of the FakeXMLHttpRequest API
  server.requests[0].respond(
    200,
    { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    JSON.stringify([{ id: 1, text: "Provide examples", done: true }])
  )

  assert(callback.calledOnce)
```

Compiled to JavaScript, the before and after functions looks like this:

```
before(function() {
  var server;
  return server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
});
after(function() {
  return server.restore();
});
```

So as you see, the variable server is declared within the before function and therefor can't be used outside of the *wrong* scope.

Comment: The `server.requests[0]` line should fail, since `server` isn't initialised at that point, no...!?

Comment: That's correct and i don't seem to gete it working, but that's a problem for later, the solution you mentioned works fine (on other code) with the same before, after structure. Exactly for this fail I need to initialise `server` before the `before()` function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
server = undefined  # or null, or false
before -> server = ...
after -> server.restore
```

While in Javascript you can do `var foo;`, in CoffeeScript you need to assign *something* to create the variable. But since `var foo;` means the value of `foo` is `undefined`, just assign `undefined` to create the same effect.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I did try the server = null before which wasn't working. But with this confimation I know it must be my code which is wrong.