Registering automapper-ts in Global Context not working - Angular App Reference undefined
After updating to Angular 18 the node package automapper-ts is no longer working.
When trying to register Automapper in global context, app is undefined, thus the Reference to the Angular App cannot be resolved. Anyone the same prob?
automapper.js
var automapper = (function (app) {
    app.automapper = AutoMapperJs.AutoMapper.getInstance();   <---  ERROR
    return app.automapper;
})(this);


I wonder how this used to work in the first place. Could be by pure chance. How was this automapper.js file integrated into the Angular app?

Also, are you using SSR? If not, why don't you save the automapper instance somewhere in the window?

how would I save the automapper instance in the window? Any resource on this topic you would share?

You can add custom properties to the window object, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/12743007/5470544

Well, I look for another solution, something critical like app should be working no matter what version is used, maybe something how it is initialized changed, would like to know what and how

Could you please elaborate what app is, ideally with a link to the official documentation? I have never seen this in Angular.

it is an angular project using node modules. these two code "namespaces" must have a connection somehow.
it is done, in previous angular version, that in the node package´s code (automapper-ts) used the reference of the angular app, got the automapper set as in the snippet above, making it angular app wide available.
Now with update of both Angular and NodeJS this connection between node modules may be done different and that´s why it is not working?! Dont exactly know what to search for.

This seems to be an issue generated by the new Angular builder introduced from version 17 that uses Vite + esbuild to compile.
The temporary solution I found is to use the old compiler by setting in the angular.json file the option builder  to "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser".
You also have to rename the property "browser": "src/main.ts" to "main": "src/main.ts".
Also there is this pull reqest that should fix the problem but at this point I think it will never be accepted.
