# Is Multiple browser window with single time login possible in Java

Tags: java, web-applications, cookies, jakarta-ee, session-cookies

I have a simple requirement. I have an web application which has a login page, a dashboard and few other pages.

If the user wants to open the application in multiple browser window from a single computer, then I want the user to login only once in first browser window. From next time onwards, whenever user hits the application URL in another different browser window(or tab) in the same Computer, then the application should redirect the user to dashboard without a fresh login. So that user does not have to login each time he opens the application in another browser window.

Is this complete scenario possible in Java/J2EE using JSP and Struts. Here I am using container managed login in Struts for the authentication (login). I need to maintain different HTTP sessions for each window (this is inherent requirement of the application).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the single sign-on architecture, or other solutions (like OpenId) which do authentication without end user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

In the same browser (IE, Firefox, Chrome etc), this is easily achieved with (session) cookies etc.

After login, just set a cookie that subsequent page loads will read from.

Read this question for some good additional related information:

[Managing webapp session data/controller flow for multiple tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479995/managing-webapp-session-data-controller-flow-for-multiple-tabs)

As @Edwin Buck has already mentioned, have a look at OpenID (or a similar single-sign-on framework):

[OpenID](http://openid.net/)

You've also got the option of using the client's IP address, but this is hideously insecure.

Comment: Note that this can have some very negative consequences if you don't take measures to protect against abuse.  Cookies are generally world readable, and if you don't do checking beyond the presence of a cookie, the some other website can easily query your cookies and the present them to your website to effectively login as the original client.

Comment: @Edwin. Very good point, I'm sure he'll address security appropriately for the level required by his application.