# Multiple users login to web application on same browser

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have developed 1 web application but when multiple users are login on the same browser than jsp page of first user is changed by jsp page of second user.

Comment: Yes, this is how the internet works. What is your question?

Comment: possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479995/managing-webapp-session-data-controller-flow-for-multiple-tabs/4480310#4480310

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can have multiple sessions simultaneously using a unique browser. Each time you create a new session, the session cookie which is used to track the current session is replaced by a new one.

Comment: that means my application is working fine and session handling is also correct. so, problem is with bowser(i am using mozila firefox)

Comment: The problem is not with the browser. All the browsers behave the same way. The problem is with your expectations: you can't have multiple sessions simultaneously on a single browser.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your browser doesn't use a new session for each open tab. If you are using firefox you can install a special plugin to handle that behaviour for you. http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2009/12/05/Session-per-tab-in-Firefox/

Answer (score 0):

Explanation on [Spring Security FAQ page](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-concurrent-session-same-browser) should answer the behaviour you encountered:

> Browsers generally maintain a single session per browser instance. You
>   cannot have two separate sessions at once. So if you log in again in
>   another window or tab you are just reauthenticating in the same
>   session. The server doesn't know anything about tabs, windows or
>   browser instances. All it sees are HTTP requests and it ties those to
>   a particular session according to the value of the the JSESSIONID
>   cookie that they contain. When a user authenticates during a session,
>   Spring Security's concurrent session control checks the number of
>   other authenticated sessions that they have. If they are already
>   authenticated with the same session, then re-authenticating will have
>   no effect.