# Passing variable from action class (Struts 2) to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, session, struts2, ognl

Technology used Struts2 and JSP
In Jsp I am checking my session value as whether it is set or not.

```
<s:if test="%{#session.sessionKey}">
```

Now I have another random variable `rndmVar` in my Action class(I can not set this variable in session scope.), now my session key will be `sessionKey` variable appended by `rndmVar` value, so how will check this  new session key in JSP.

i want something like

```
<s:if test="%{#session.sessionKey+rndmVar}">  //session key appended by rndmVar value.
```

First problem how will pass this variable from action class to JSP, and than how will I check it in JSP.

i tried something like

```
public String rndmVar;
public String getRndmVar() {
  return rndmVar;
}
public void setRndmVar(String rndmVar) {
  this.lang = lang;
}
```

than in method of action class(this method of action class will redirect to JSP.), I setted this random variable value.

```
setRndmVar("rndmfdfkad");
```

I thought var `rndmVar` was added in value stack and can be accessed using OGNL. but this didn't work.

Now I am putting values in session object in action class as.

```
String randomVar="fadfjk";
String newSessionKey="sessionKey"+randomVar;
session.put(newSessionKey,"value_part");
```

Now in Jsp I want to check whether `newSessionKey` variable is set or not. Now how can I pass dynamically key value to JSP.

```
<s:if test="#session['sessionKey' + rndmVar] != null">
```

above Syntax is not working, in fact it is always giving `null` and going in else loop.

In my action class

```
session.put("sessionKey"+rndmVar,"businessList"); //where businessList is ArrayList<BusinessLogicDTO> businessList
```

I am able to see `rndmVar` value in scriplet tags in JSP.

```
<% System.out.println(" Random var value passed from action class 2 JSP "+request.getParameter("rndmVar")); %>
```

Comment: What is the point in appending random values to the session key?

Comment: @Aleksandr M -- basically this random number is specific to my tab(it will be unique for that tab for all operation done by user), if uerr use 'open link in new tab' option than than new random variable shall be created for new tab. Since session is shared by all tabs of browser so i am differenciating by key.

Comment: @Aleksandr M--I have not decided till yet, may be by some sharing object of JVM/ by some business logic on static hashmap.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4479995/1700321.

Comment: @Aleksandr M  Kindly see edited section as session key passing dynamically syntax is not working.

Comment: You shouldn't accept answer until you've verified that it works.

Comment: Put `<s:property value="rndmVar"/>` and `<s:property value="#session['sessionKey' + rndmVar]"/>` in your jsp and see what it prints.

Comment: @Aleksandr M... both are printing nothing on gui.

Comment: It means that you haven't set `rndmVar` in your action.

Comment: @Aleksandr M.... I can see it as request parameter in scriplet tag, it is printing correct value <% System.out.println(" Random var value passed from action class 2 JSP "+request.getParameter("rndmVar")); %>

Comment: Request parameter isn't the same thing as an S2 value stack.

Comment: You can use `#parameters['rndmVar']` to get value from parameters, but it is rather ugly, better set it properly into value stack.

Comment: @Aleksandr M...As u have already said,For all the values where rndmVar is added in value stack,syntax is working perfectly fine,so for value stack variables there is no problem, but somewhere in code i have also used reuest parameter which values will be also appended in 'sessionKey',basicall i want to do something like <s:if test="#session['sessionKey'+ #parameters['rndmVar']] != null">...but this syntax is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `rndmVar` field with getter/setter in your action and this page is a result of this particular action then you can access this variable like this in JSP.

```
<s:property value="rndmVar"/>
```

To get the desired value from the session use this:

```
<s:if test="#session['sessionKey' + rndmVar] != null">
```

To get the `rndmVar` value from request parameters use this:

```
<s:if test="#session['sessionKey'+ #parameters['rndmVar'][0]]">
```

Note the `#parameters['some_key']` will return array of Strings, because it can be more than one parameter with `some_key` in the request. So you if you want the first parameter in this array you need to use `[0]` to get it.

Also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4479995/1700321) to get hints about managing session data for multiple tabs.

Answer (score 1):

You can't check the value is set like this, unless the value is of type `Boolean`. Instead if the value is not set it must contain a `null`. Then you can check it like this

```
<s:if test="#session.sessionKey != null">
```

A random value can be used as an index for the collection defined by the `sessionKey`.

For example if `sessionKey` is the `Map<String, Object>` and it's put into the `#session` then you can check the object using a random value

```
<s:if test="#session.sessionKey[rndmVar] != null">
```

Comment: ...Kindly please see edited secion, as i was not able to clarify u my problem.

Comment: The key value you can pas from the action with getter, but you'd better use a map for the sessionKey and use a key to access it instead of random session variable.

Comment: <s:property value="#session['resultParameter']" />   <s:if test="resultParameter == success">
           <div class="errormessage">            
                             <h1>Hi</h1>         
           </div>
          </s:if>

Comment: s:property prints value is success why am not getting hi message