# How to store data in session so that it works for simultaneous log-ins also

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

During the Application startup , using the login Id of the User , i am making a Database call and loading all of his accounts and setting them in the session as shown 
`session.setAttribute("userinfo",userinfo);`

and i am using this accounts information in the service layer to do a check before making a call to the Database

Now the problem is that if a User (who is having multiple accounts ) logs simulatunosly into a same  browser , its creating same sessionid , as a result the session is having only the information of the last logged in user .

is there anyway i can solve this , may be the way i am storing data

please help

Comment: I think you just need to update existing session with new information. Some code on what you are doing may help in providing valid solution.

Comment: Wait, isnt it better to prevent simeltaneous logins from the same browser ??

Answer (score 0):

May not be the best solution but this will help to solve the problem.

What you could do would be to associate the userid with the sessionid and on every pageload / clicks, you will check if the sessionid matches the login user's userid. If it matches, disregard and run the page as usual else you can fetch the user info from the database and reassign the variables again.

Comment: Sorry , i did not understand that , could you please elobrate

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URL rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243201/session-shared-in-between-tabs/6244094#6244094) instead of cookies. The downside is that the session ID is exposed in the URL.