# Stoping a User to login based on SESSIONID

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to store data in session so that it works for simultaneous log-ins also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199198/how-to-store-data-in-session-so-that-it-works-for-simultaneous-log-ins-also)

I am storing  information in the session and i am able to retrieve the same for single user.
The trouble starts when  user  2 logged in from same  browser (for example chrome) from the same machine. The 2nd logged in user, overwrite the session information of first user.

becuase the browsers are created same sessionid .

So please tell me what is the best way from stopping  User 2 being logged in  , if he comes with the Same SessionID ??

Means my question can we stop a User based on SessionID ??

Comment: @rene not a very useful dupe though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Please give more details about the technologies you are using.. like the application server, the framework of your application.

Just for information, the browser tabs share the session data, so two users logged into the application from the same machine using the same browser can have separate session ids only if they using two different browser windows and not two different tabs.

Need more details to give further answer.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done but with a lot of effort from your part. The way to go is by rewriting URLS.

Example:
Request comes from www.yoursite.com/ (notice the absence of any parameters on the URL). Then you return a URL with a self-generated id like www.yoursite.com?id=abcd . Notice that here you link the id to the actual request. From now on, for any request to the site you should rewrite this same id.

If a second request comes from another tab, to www.yoursite.com then you will create another different id and so on.

IMO, you should not do it because you ruin the whole session management philosophy that is built in the web server. I think you should consider other options to solve your problem.

You can read a similar article here [How to differ sessions in browser-tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368653/how-to-differ-sessions-in-browser-tabs)