# How can I store state for an individual browser tab/window?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm developing a single page jQuery & Backbone.js web app. The backend is a JBoss 6 application server.

Until now we had the following structure:

- There is only one servlet (front controller). Every request from the JavaScript client goes through here.
- In the servlet - at the first request of a certain JS client - I make a look p to a stateful session bean. For the next requests of this client, I store the result of the look up in an HTTP session container. So every JS client has exactly one stateful session bean. This connection is kept by a session cookie.

Now I have an additional requirement:

When the user has two browser tabs (in one browser), they should have two isolated instances of the web app in every browser tab. Because of that I have a problem with session cookies because this session cookie is for all browser tabs.

I have to change the structure so that:

- The servlet has to generate a new session ID for the first request of a certain JS client. This session ID is communicated to the client.
- With every POST to the backend the JS client has to send this session ID.

My question is:

Until now I saved the result of the look up in an HTTP Session object and I hadn't to think about generating a session ID.  But now I have to store this somewhere else, where?

Has anybody experience with this kind of setting and can help me?

**Update:**
Thank you BalusC for this very interesting approach.
When I understood you well, this means:

All individual JS clients of the tabs of *one* browser share one HTTP session object.   And in this HTTP session object, every tab has its own entry point.   That sounds really good.   So I still can use the whole HTTP session infrastructure and don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autogenerate an unique value on the initial GET request which you store and pass around on every subsequent postback as a hidden input value. Use this unique value as identifier of the session attribute representing the view-scoped data.

During the 1st request on a brand new session, do:

```
Map<String, ViewData> viewScope = new HashMap<String, ViewData>();
session.setAttribute("viewScope", viewScope);
```

*(the `ViewData` represents the view-specific data you'd like to track across postbacks on the same view)*

During every GET request, do:

```
String viewDataId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
viewScope.put(viewDataId, new ViewData());
request.setAttribute("viewDataId", viewDataId);
```

During generating the HTML, do:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="viewDataId" value="${viewDataId}" />
```

During every POST request, do:

```
ViewData viewData = viewScope.get(request.getParameter("viewDataId"));
// Get/set view-specific data in there.
```

Make sure that jQuery also passes this hidden input around (which shouldn't be a big problem if you already properly use `$(form).serialize()` or e.g. AjaxForm plugin to ajaxify the forms).

If you're familiar with Java EE's MVC framework [JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info), then it may be useful to know that its `@ViewScoped` annotation works roughly the same as described above. See also a.o. [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

Answer (score 0):

You can use session tracking with URL rewriting. See here:

[Session shared in between tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243201/session-shared-in-between-tabs)

Comment: I believe you don't understand how session tracking actually works in the client side. It isn't possible to create separate sessions per browser window/tab this way.

Comment: Why not? Each tab could have it´s own session-id as GET parameter in the URL, like this: http:\\www.myapp.com?session-id=02393vdr8t. The ID is handled by the WebServer but you have to encode each URL. It´s similar to your solution, but not as hidden input value. See here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243201/session-shared-in-between-tabs[link].