# ASP.net c# Avoid open the same window twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, window, state

I'm developing a web application. I have a small problem with sessions when a user open the same window in the same session.

For example: Now, the user open the page user and he select a user I store this object in session (Session["user"] = user), if he open the same window in another tab browser and he select other user I override the session value (Session"["user"] = user).....

I'm thinking solutions:

- Avoid that the user can open the same window in the same PC
- Create unique id for each page opened by the user

What do you think? 
Wich is the better solution?

Thanks for your help and best regards,

Comment: Why do you care? If the user opens up two tabs to use your application and the second tab replaces a session variable used by the first, so what? I wouldn't try and avoid this, it seems like a reasonable use of a web app.

Comment: I know! but the user update the data from the first tab and the value of the session is of the second!

Comment: You can't read out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368653/how-to-differ-sessions-in-browser-tabs)

Comment: @EmmanuelN I kind of agree except the first question was "What do you think?". I've answered that question. I think I've also implicitly answered the second question: "Which is the better solution?" and to me, neither of those solutions are good or any better than the other.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can prevent a user from opening the same page in two different tabs or browsers.
So, if you need do make sure each window is a distinct "session" in your application, you'll need some kind of unique ID, perhaps stored in a hidden HTML input.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance you have to use cookieless sessions - in web.config  in system.web

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20" cookieless="UseUri" />
```

what this does is insert a session id into the url  so you get something like, www.host.com/(abc15284dndhjkdm)/app.aspx.  thisis then unique per tab and so the user can have uniqie session per tab.

Edit: - here is the code for the aspx pages i show at web3.adprs.net/test/test1.aspx i mention below

Test1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="test1.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication4.test1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head runat="server">
    <title></title> </head>
     <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        Enter User <asp:TextBox ID="user" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="go" runat="server" Text="Go" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </body></html>
```

Test1.aspx.vb

```
Public Class test1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub go_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles go.Click
        Session("user") = user.Text
        Response.Redirect("test2.aspx")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Test2.aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    Your user from session is <%=Session("user").ToString%>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20" cookieless="UseUri" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just checked it but allways put the same id in the url.

Comment: Did you make the web.config change - this is standard asp.net functionality i have many sites that are set up with thousands of users many of whom will log in on seperate tabs and it works ok.  If you open a new tab to www.site.com/main.aspx, it will see you dont have a session token in the url and send a redirect to www.site.com/{uniqueid}/main.aspx.   Maybe you are copying and pasting the full url into the new tab, you should only go to the url without the token.

Comment: Yes I did but when I open the same page with the same session de uniqueid is the same....

Comment: sorry - i dont understand - what page url did you open originally and what do you open in the second tab ?   As i said this is the standard asp.net methodology as produced by microsoft for handling this common situation, so it would normally work ok.

Comment: I explain my steps, I enter to my app, I login with my user and password, in the url i can view a unique id, then i go to users page, then I open a new tab, enter to my app, go to user (I'm logged already). I check the ID's of the tabs and both are the same!

Comment: Are you using basic authentication, or asp.net membership , or something else to login  ?

Comment: My own authentication, I read login and password and I check with a database.

Comment: Hi  Ok - i have done a little example site - go to web3.adprs.net/test/test1.aspx    and type in a name, and press go, then open another tab to web3.adprs.net/test/test1.aspx and type in another name and press go, visit the first tab and press f5, it should remain the same as you entered for that session - the session is keyed to the unique id in the url. As I said this is standard asp.net functionality for this very circumstance. If it is not working for you there must be a very specific circumstance, and it would help me to understand what this is.   HTH :)

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why in my project doesn't work. I'm going to try again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your responses.

I read the post [How to differ sessions in browser-tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368653/how-to-differ-sessions-in-browser-tabs) and I found severals solutions to generate unique id per tab.

The solutions are:

- https://sites.google.com/site/sarittechworld/track-client-windows
- https://github.com/chrisdew/subsession
- Implement my own unique id per page

I'm going to review them and I tell you the result.

If somebody knows another solution, allways is wellcome!

Best regards,