# How to differ session in different tabs?

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I wanted to open an asp.net application with a new session in the same browser but in a different tab.
Please let me know the solution if it is possible.

Comment: Check out this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368653/how-to-differ-sessions-in-browser-tabs?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to configure session don't use cookies for session identifier and open new window with client code. To implement such approach you need to set `cookieless` atribute of the `session` element in web.config file to `UseUri`. Be warned about available side-effects in this case (quote from the MSDN):

> **Note**  When you configure an AJAX-enabled ASP.NET Web site, use only the default value of UseCookies for the cookieless attribute. Settings that use cookies encoded in the URL are not supported by the ASP.NET AJAX client script libraries.

After that you can open new tab with new session with javascript as below:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
Session Id:
<%= Session.SessionID %>
<hr />
<input type="button" value="Open New Tab" onclick="openNewTab()" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openNewTab() {
        window.open(location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/Default.aspx", "_blank");
    }
</script>
</form>
```

Or you can to implement custom SessionIDManager that not use cookies for session identifier: [SessionIDManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.aspx)