# How to make two or more browser tabs load the same module without interfering with each other?

Tags: openxava

When I open two o more browser tabs pointing to the same module, the contents of tabs interfere with each other in many ways ( filters, sorting, list/detail mode ). It looks like it's no possible to make different things in differents tabs with the same module.
How to isolate each browser tab's session ? Is there a way to accomplish that ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in this link:
[How to differ sessions in browser-tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368653/how-to-differ-sessions-in-browser-tabs)
This is not an OpenXava specific issue.

However, you can define two identical modules in application.xml with different names, and load each module in its own browser tab. We could improve OpenXava to allow different session state for each tab. Are you willing to make this improvement and contribute it back to OpenXava?