# How to login as different user in different tabs in a browser?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I am using .net 2.0. I want to open a application in different tabs in a browser. I want to login as different users in different tabs in a browser. [The Application menus will be loaded based on particular user session.]  Is it possible??

Comment: To be honest dont know much about this. Hope this will help you... [How to differ sessions in browser-tabs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368653/how-to-differ-sessions-in-browser-tabs)

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET cookieless sessions and cookieless forms authentication should do the trick.

I've never done it before, and it doesn't look like a lot of people have, but basically, it stores whatever would normally be in a cookie in the URL instead. Because of this, there would be nothing shared between browser tabs/windows.

I don't know how much work is involved in making that happen - I know in theory it's just a config setting, but I don't know if it's really as easy as that.

Answer (score 0):

In IE you can go to File -> New Session which would allow you to have two windows. You can log into the same application as different users this way (and I regularly do). I'm sure the other browsers have something similar.