# Javascript Cookie related issue

Tags: javascript

I am facing a problem with a backend using cookies .

The UI technology is JSP and i have login to the application and performed some operations.

At that time i copied the url and opened a new tab and pasted the copied url

In this case i would like the user to be redirected to login page.

Comment: Could you re-word your question? It's a bit difficult to understand at the moment.

Comment: Try using session instead of cookie. If u just write a cookie with `loggedin=true` then its very easy to break in.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i understood from your question :

Your webserver uses cookie to store user session info , you want the user to be redirected to login page when he copy pastes the link onto a new tab .

This is what happens when you do what u said u did :

When a user requests a url from a new tab with an established session in the previous tab , the cookie is sent along with this newtab request hence the webserver renders the page to this request since it is legitimate.

However , the same will not work if you fire the request using a different browser.[In this case the backend will redirect the user to login page (if you've identified the url is without cookie info and programmed a redirect to login page in your server code).]

I don't think this can be done using cookie based session handling .

Please do check this link [How to differ sessions in browser-tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368653/how-to-differ-sessions-in-browser-tabs)