# Login both admin and user in same browser at a time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have to login both admin and user in same browser in Laravel. In Zend Frame Work it is possible using [`$authNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Zend_Auth')`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.basic_usage.html). Is there any similar approach available in Laravel?

Comment: I guess admin is an user already.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin yes admin is a user in same db table.

Comment: So, what exactly are you trying to achieve then?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin $_SESSION['admin']['user'] = "adminuser";
$_SESSION['userside']['user'] = "normaluser";

Comment: Sounds similar to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311771/laravel-and-multi-sessions-from-the-same-browser/33404870#33404870

Comment: Is it possible to implement this functionality in Laravel 5.2 using auth guards?

Comment: Maybe you are willing to implement Roles and Permissions?