# How to create multiple sessions laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I have multiple login (user & admin )
Problem when user logout, all sessions are destroyed
I want to create a session for the web guard like (laravel_session_web) and a session for the admin guard like (laravel_session_admin)
When logging out, only the session related to the guard is destroyed

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311771/laravel-and-multi-sessions-from-the-same-browser

Comment: Thank you, but I can't write any function in a session file or config, like 'cookie' => 'laravel_session' . user()->id,