# Multiple 'about:blank' - localStorage

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a bookmarklet, and the bookmarklet goes to `about:blank`, then stores data under `localStorage` (technically, it downloads a script that stores data under `localStorage`)

The idea is that it downloads a script, and stores it under `localStorage`. That way, it doesn't have to download it again. However, there is no way of ensuring that one of the scripts won't try to edit the contents of another script (in `localStorage`).

So, I was wondering if it was possible to get a fresh context for `localStorage`, e.g. via going  to `about:blank/xyz`. However, I do not want this to go to a website, even if the website is specially designed for this. I want this to be entirely local (the entire purpose behind this is to save bandwidth).

Or, being able to somehow sandbox `localStorage` would work too (in fact, that would be much preferred)

Any thoughts?

**TL;DR** I want to be able to have a fresh context for `localStorage`, without accessing a website (e.g. via `about:blank`, hence the title: Multiple about:blank's)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065157/how-to-have-separate-sessionstorages-for-iframes-on-same-origin

Comment: I edited the question to make it a bit clearer (the TL;DR part). What is plnkr? And, two bookmarklets running under the same context (`about:blank`) have access to the same `localStorage`.

Comment: plnkr http://plnkr.co is a website that allow use of `localStorage` to demonstrate `html` , `js` ,`css`

Comment: Could try creating an `objectURL` to store data that should only be accessible from original `location.href` that created the blob url. Not entirely certain what expected requirement, or result is ?

Comment: I looked into `createObjectURL`, but I'm not exactly sure how to run it? I tried running it with a WebWorker, but it can't access `window` (including `localStorage` and the DOM)

Comment: The approach would be to substitute `objectURL` for `localStorage` ; not certain what expected result is ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean ... could you give a code example? I'll edit the question and explain what I am looking for a bit better :) **update**: edited! I hope this clarifies it!

Comment: What is the purpose of having multiple `localStorage` instances ?

Comment: See the edit :) It's basically so that each script that my bookmarklet runs (these are arbitrary, could be any script) will have a fresh context, and will not modify the `localStorage` of any other script

Comment: Reviewed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065157/how-to-have-separate-sessionstorages-for-iframes-on-same-origin ?

Comment: I did .... so, there is no way to do this?

Comment: Not entirely certain if possible using `localStorage` ; only workaround solution provided at linked Question was to utilize `https:` protocol . Still not certain what expected result is or purpose of using `localStorage` ?

Comment: _“so that each script that my bookmarklet runs […] will have a fresh context, and will not modify the localStorage of any other script ”_ – so how will that bookmarklet access the stored data when it/the specific script is run the next time? (Assuming that is a requirement somehow, because otherwise why would you be using localStorage in the first place?) Based on what criterion would you want that association to happen (if the URL is out of question, because the same)?

Comment: @CBroe The idea is  that there is one 'master' script, that can access all of the scripts (the real `localStorage` object). And then, it would run another, 3rd party, script, but give it only a subset of the `localStorage` object (e.g. in pseudo-code `localStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.script_xyz_storage)`), and once the script is done, it would save the changes (`localStorage.script_xyz_storage = ...`).

Comment: @MiJyn In that case, could do just that; create an unique property of `localStorage` parsed object for when a bookmarklet is launched

Comment: @guest271314 Could you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: When bookmarklet is launched, create a `localStorage` item that is incremented; e.g.; `localStorage.setItem("a1")` , `localStorage.setItem("a2")` , `localStorage.setItem("z1")` , `localStorage.setItem("z2")`

Comment: Okay, but what would that accomplish?

Comment: If `localStorage.setItem("a1")` exists , create `localStorage.setItem("a2")` ; the two properties, values would be unique ? Is concern that  `localStorage.setItem("a2")` would access  `localStorage.setItem("a1")` ? If yes, why ?

Comment: _“However, there is no way of ensuring that one of the scripts won't try to edit the contents of another script”_ – so what/where from are those scripts? Why would they behave in such a “malicious” manner?

Comment: To both gues271314 and CBroe (I can't tag more than one person), it executes arbitrary scripts that the user feeds it (this is a "framework" of sorts). The issue is that one of the scripts that the user feeds might act maliciously :)

Comment: Prevent the scripts from acting maliciously ? Again, not certain why `localStorage` is being used here ? What do scripts do ? Can you create a plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate ?

Comment: _"it executes arbitrary scripts that the user feeds it"_ How would a script affect another user ? The user would effectively be acting maliciously towards themselves ?

Comment: @guest271314 Here is an example: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15049909/ . As you can see, the malicious script can do whatever it wants.

Comment: @MiJyn Yes, though user would be calling a malicious script that would only affect themselves ?

Comment: The issue is if multiple scripts were to be run, a malicious script could edit others' scripts (and their data) :)