# how to maintain count value over a Browser using HttpSession in java?

Tags: java, httpsession

I want to maintain onw count value over a Http browser. 
Example :

If browser once open and click on submit button make count as one. again click on button make count as two. and I want count should be less than two.

Consider a count is : private static int count &
maxCount is : private int maxCount = 3
code:

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
     HttpSession session = request.getSession();
     session.setAttribute("count", ++count);
     if(session.getAttribute("count") <= maxCount){
         //proccess stuff
     }else{
        //give maxcount completed message
     }
 }
```

It will work fine when open a browser first time but if I open a browser in another window then it will showing me **maxCount completed message**

I recognize this count is a static variable and gets memory once and all But what can I do for this. I want this count value as again zero when I open in a another window of the browser?

Answer (score 1):

You can change like this.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
     HttpSession session = request.getSession();
     Integer count = (Integer)session.getAttribute("count"); 
     if( count == null) {
         count  = 1;
         session.setAttribute("count", count);   
     }
     if(count <= maxCount){
         session.setAttribute("count", ++count);
         // do other stuff.
     }else{
        //give maxcount completed message
     }
 }
```

No need to have static variable or even a private variable.

Comment: It is not the working properly. I want count variable as again zero when I'm hitting URL to the next window of the browser.

Comment: @ketan when hitting from next window the count attribute will not be there in the session so you can assume it as zero.

Comment: I tried with that, It's count will be incrementing further when we are hitting url to next window.

Comment: Is it next window or tab?. If it is tab then it is not a new session.

Comment: sorry my mistake I mean new tab... If we hit url in the new tab I want count value as a zero then what is the solution for making such a complicated situation as easy...???

Comment: @ketan New tab mean it would be in the same session. I will check if there is anyway to find tab info and get back to you on this.

Comment: @ketan May be creating unique id and storing it in sessionStorage should help you. Check this [SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368653/how-to-differ-sessions-in-browser-tabs)