# How to handle Different Session in different tabs of same browser?

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net, frontend, web-frontend

I would like to open different tabs with different session but currently I did not found any procedure?

I have searched my methods but did not found any solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368653/how-to-differ-sessions-in-browser-tabs

Comment: Please do not tag unrelated products to question

Comment: how you manage single session? if with javascript token based session then I have a solution.

Comment: @B001ᛦ i did not tag any unrelated products I only tag which can answer my question.

Comment: @KiplDeveloper No, I did not work with token i only save UserID in cookie.

Comment: _i did not tag any unrelated products..._ Well there is no javascript, no php etc added to your question

Comment: @TechleadzTeam please put your code here.

Comment: you can manage UserID with url like gmail handle multiple session like-
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=wm#inbox
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/?tab=wm#inbox

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage and SessionStorage are the two features of HTML5 which can be used for multiple session in different tabs and every Tab will have different session key and session will be destroyed when tab closed.