# windows.sessionStorage chrome vs opera

Tags: javascript

I am working on an app where a user can edit a "thing". I don't want multiple users to edit the same thing at the same time, so I've implemented a "locking" technique. It seems to be working fairly well. If you try to open a thing that is locked by someone else, you can view the thing, but in read-only mode.

To accomplish this, I am using window.sessionStorage, like this:

```
function sessionNumber() {
    if (window.sessionStorage.sessionNumber) {
        return window.sessionStorage.sessionNumber;
    }
    else {
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000 + 1);
        window.sessionStorage.sessionNumber = num;
        return num;
    }
}
```

In chrome, if you open the same "thing" in a different tab, you get a different session number. In Opera, if you open the same thing in a different tab, you get the same session number.

To be clear, I prefer Chrome's behavior over Opera's. Is there a cross browser way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Use `localStorage` instead of `sessionStorage`.

Comment: But how does this lock between different users? Browser storage is specific to that user. If you want something to coordinate between users it has to be on the server.

Comment: I store the number in a sql table on the server. There's a whole bunch of functionality built up around this, but it hinges one each tab of each browser getting a different sessionNumber.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Opera, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368653/how-to-differ-sessions-in-browser-tabs for what the spec says.

Comment: Note that if a user *duplicates* a tab, the session storage from the original tab is *copied* to the new tab.